# Draw points as ovals using java swing

Tags: java, swing, point

I have a point with `[x, y]` coordinate, for example 
`Point p = new Point(1, 2)`. I want to visualize it. However, I want this point to an oval, like in the picture below.

[image]

How can I do that using `java Swing`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Determine the size of the oval you want, for example 10 px. Then draw the oval with the x and y points starting at the `Point` (x and y), minus half the `size`. Something like:

```
public class PointsPanel extends JPanel {
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    int size = 10;
    ...
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Point p : points) {
            int x = p.x - size/2;
            int y = p.y - size/2;
            g.drawOval(x, y, size, size);
        }
    }
}
```

For more general details on painting, see [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Also see the [Graphics API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) for other `drawXxx` and `fillXxx` methods.

Answer (score 0):

From the image you posted, what you need is a graph layout library like [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/index.html)(not sure about current status of this project). You can follow peeskillet's answer but need to take care of problems like overlapping ovals etc.